# On Ubuntu 22.04 with VirtualBox, Windows 10 guest won't run anymore

Tags: virtualbox

I've been using a VirtualBox Windows 10 Home guest on my Ubuntu system (now 22.04, with VirtualBox 6.1.34) for several years until yesterday, when it failed to start. Various attempts have yielded Windows stop codes including IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL, KMODE EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED, and UNEXPECTED STORE EXCEPTION, so the failure path doesn't seem quite consistent. On some trials, I've even gotten as far as logging into my guest, but it crashes soon thereafter. Thinking that the VM image might have become corrupted, I restored a version of the .vdi file that I'd been using successfully last month, along with the then-current .nvram and .vbox files. I'm still failing to start the guest. Has anyone else seen recent failures with Windows 10 VirtualBox guests, and/or does anyone have suggestions for next steps based on similar experiences?

UPDATE: I've now seen a number of references to issues with VB 6.1.34 on other Linux distributions (Fedora, Manjaro, Arch), which suggests that the problem is specific to particular kernel versions and that VB 6.1.36 may provide resolution in at least some cases.

Comment: Similar here: after a day's work it crashes now repeatedly. Tried to use an older snapshot but that doesn't seem to be the answer... some driver / configuration issue, presumably unrelated to the state of the Win 10 guest... tbd :/

Comment: a lot of people reported problems with virtualbox on new kernel, you gotta wait for the fix, or maybe downgrade your kernel

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty  For what it's worth, I was having problems as well with Ubuntu as both the host and guest OS'.  For the host OS, I went down to the 5.15.0-40 kernel from 5.15.0-47 and all of the problems were gone.  Perhaps this will help your problems as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem.  installing VB 6.1.38 appears to have resolved the issue.  Follow VB installation guide for Debian based Linux: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: That installed, but got me the following error when trying to start my guest: Failed to load R0 module /usr/lib/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0: Unable to locate imported symbol 'SUPR0FpuBegin' for module 'VMMR0.r0' (VERR_SYMBOL_NOT_FOUND).
Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SYMBOL_NOT_FOUND).


Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Comment: @wevdap I got the same error message with 5.15.0-47 of the kernel (and, I think, 46).  So I went "way back" to 40...

Comment: Installing VB 6.1.38 on 5.15.0-47 resolves the Windows guest crashing issue for me.  Did you guys ensure to completely remove all the VB related packages before installing?  Mismatch of versions cuold clearly cause some errors.

Comment: So far so good, thanks! Did apt purge virtualbox-6.1 followed by reinstall per VB instructions, and my guest started and is running so far! Will be attentive to see if crashes follow, but I'm hopeful that this will prove to be a lasting fix.